# Is there any way to accomplish what ARM's 'STMIA' or 'LDMIA' do using the AVR instruction set?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, avr, memcpy

I need to sequentially copy a given memory location into a register set. As far as I can tell, there is no AVR instruction to increment or decrement a register the way `STMIA` and `LDMIA` do. Would anyone know how to walk around this?

Thanks in advance,

George

Comment: Assuming you have a free register, just use a loop.

Comment: @Jester Yes, but I can't tell the assembler to copy it into a different register each iteration can I? I need `FFFF:FFF7` into `r25:r22` assuming that each register is 8 bit.

Comment: Registers are memory mapped, it's just a `memcpy`. For 4 registers, I don't think it will be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVR doesn't have an exact equivalent, but ST and LD both have forms that post-increment or pre-decrement the index register being used. Combined with the fact that registers are directly accessible in the first 32 memory locations, the ARM instructions can be emulated to some degree.

Comment: Got it to work by using the `Z` register to load in data from program memory and the `X` register to write it into memory space mapped to the general purpose registers. I must give @Jester credit for leading me to realize registers could be written to using `ST` instructions within the first 25 address slots.

Comment: @GeorgeMorgan: 32, not 25, as I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but `26-32` are the `X, Y, and Z` registers. `C` functions only utilize `0-25`, which is where my application is.